# Python keyboard input in terminal while UDP socket server is listening

Tags: python, sockets, udp

How to send socket data based on keyboard input in terminal while receiving incoming UDP data? Data will be send through socket after `enter` key is pressed included LF (line feed character).

I only have this minimal UDP server:

```
import socket
SERV_IPV4, SERV_PORT = ("192.168.43.150", 7777)
udpSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udpSock.bind((SERV_IPV4,SERV_PORT))

while 1:
  dataRecv, CLNT_ADDR = udpSock.recvfrom(1024)
  print(dataRecv, CLNT_ADDR)
```

What I expect about program is moreless like how netcat command work: `nc -ulp 7777`

Comment: Have you had a look at threading?

Comment: @iggy890 but it's C class private IP address, not a public IP.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****Use Threading****

```
import socket, threading
SERV_IPV4, SERV_PORT = ("192.168.43.150", 7777)
udpSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udpSock.bind((SERV_IPV4,SERV_PORT))

dataRecv = ""
CLNT_ADDR = None

def receiveData():
  global CLNT_ADDR
  global dataRecv
  while (1):
    dataRecv, CLNT_ADDR = udpSock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(dataRecv, CLNT_ADDR)

recvThread = threading.Thread(target=receiveData)
recvThread.start()
recvThread.join(0)

while (1):
  dataSend = (input() + "\n").encode()
  print(dataSend)
  udpSock.sendto(dataSend,CLNT_ADDR)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your socket in non-blocking mode:

```
import socket

SERV_IPV4, SERV_PORT = ("192.168.43.150", 7777)
udpSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udpSock.bind((SERV_IPV4,SERV_PORT))

udpSock.setblocking(False)

while 1:
    try:
        dataRecv, CLNT_ADDR = udpSock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(dataRecv, CLNT_ADDR)
    except socket.error:
        # No input from the socket
```